# Multiple if statements with multiple conditions?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to check my page's `<title>` tag for certain key words, to show/hide a div. Each state (4 states) have 4 differrent keywords they could have in the title. I'm trying to figure out how I can write my if statement so it says

> If title has "word 1" or "word 2" or "word 3" or "word 4" do this function

Currently, I have it written like this:

```
if ($("title").text() == "Marketing" || "Marketing Product Support" || "Inbound Marketing Best Practices" || "Marketing Certification Help") {
$('.marketing-board-header').show();
}

if ($("title").text() == "Sales" || "Sales Product Support" || "Inbound Sales Best Practices" || "Sales Certification Help") {
$('.sales-board-header').show();
}

if ($("title").text() == "COS Design" || "COS Design Support" || "Share Your Work" || "Design Certification Help") {
$('.design-board-header').show();
}

if ($("title").text() == "community Ideas") {
$('.idea-board-header').show();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to hide/show the divs I'd like, am I missing something? or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your conditions will be always true

Comment: This seems like an X/Y problem, why would you need to check an elements content for all those strings, surely there are easier ways to do this?

Comment: you should use a switch statement.. it's a little cleaner, easier to read than all the ifs. see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a switch statement instead.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    switch ( jQuery('title').text() )
    {
       case "Marketing":
       case "Marketing Product Support":
       case "Inbound Marketing Best Practices": 
           jQuery('.marketing-board-header').show();
           break;
       case "Sales":
       case "Sales Product Support":
       case "Inbound Sales Best Practices": 
           jQuery('.sales-board-header').show();
           break;
    }
});
```

etc...

Comment: I forgot all about switch statements, that worked beautifully for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search DOM again and again, which is a bad practice and costly too.

Try to get the title once and use that variable for multiple checks
and there is a mistake in your if conditions too
it cannot check in the way you have done it 
Modify your code as following code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var title=$("title").text() ;
 if(title==="Marketing" || title=="Marketing Product Support" || title== "Inbound Marketing Best title==Practices" || title== "Marketing Certification Help"){
      $('.marketing-board-header').show();
}

});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `$("title").text()` does give you the value you are looking to compare, your conditions are always going to be `true`. Because in your `OR` conditions, you are providing a string, which is always going to be computed as `true`. The correct way to do this would be-

```
var title = $("title").text();
if (title == "Marketing" || title == "Marketing Product Support" || title == "Inbound Marketing Best Practices" || title == "Marketing Certification Help") {
    $('.marketing-board-header').show();
}

if (title == "Sales" || title == "Sales Product Support" || title == "Inbound Sales Best Practices" || title == "Sales Certification Help") {
    $('.sales-board-header').show();
}

if (title == "COS Design" || title == "COS Design Support" || title == "Share Your Work" || title == "Design Certification Help") {
    $('.design-board-header').show();
}

if (title == "community Ideas") {
    $('.idea-board-header').show();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you should write something like

```
if (A==B || A==C || A==D){/*...*/}
```

but you have written

```
if (A==B || C || D)
```

in this case C is evaluated as a boolean statement  itself (true/false) which, in case of a string is always true. 
So you are somehow writing

```
if($("title").text()== "Marketing" || true || true ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is each 'or' operator `||` is supposed to separate entire conditions.  Your code first evaluates `title == 'word1'` which may return true or false, but then it tries to evaluate `word2` without a condition so it returns true. So, a corrected version of this would be as follows:

```
if(title == 'word1' || title == 'word2'){
    /* code for word1 or word2 here */
}
```

A possible solution could be to use a switch statement with fall-through. Here's how it might look.

```
var title = $("title").text();
switch(title){
    case "word1":
    case "word2":
    case "word3":
        /* code for word1, word2, or word3 here */
        break;
    case "word4":
    case "word5":
        /* code for word4 or word5 here */
        break;
}
```

So, the code you write above the first break will only apply to "word1, word2, or word3". That is a little more legible than with if statements.

Comment: Good answer. See mine ;)

Comment: yep saw yours after I finished writing mine haha. great minds!

Comment: Much cleaner. (y)